# Boolean comparisons on Strings

Tags: java, string, compare

I'm learning java now. I have a book which is up to SE6 date.
Now there is an exercise that asks me:

> Write a method that takes two String arguments and uses all boolean comparisons to compare the two Strings and print the results. In main(); call your method with some different String objects.

When I tried:

```
public static void compare(String a, String b){
    System.out.println(a>b);
}
```

I got error said `> operator is not valid for type String`

Now my question is - if the book is out of date and something changed since, or am I misunderstanding something in the task?

Comment: simply use a.equals(b)

Comment: The boolean operators are indeed not valid for String objects, so no surprises there. The exercise does state Boolean comparisons, not operators, so I imagine the intent is to look at how the String Boolean methods work (equals, contains, startsWith, etc.)

Comment: u cant use > , < on objects. String is an  object in Java. So use .compareTo if you want  to compare. (corrected my comment after reading the Matthew comment)

Comment: Why is everybody recommending `equals`? `compareTo` is what you are looking for.

Comment: `a > b` was never designed to work with Strings

Comment: "and uses all boolean comparisons" since you can't simply use `<`, `>` on objects (which Strings are) and [`==` doesn't necessary do what you may think it does for references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java) you can try using these boolean operators not on strings directly, but on characters they hold since there is no problem with using boolean comparisons with `char`.

Comment: It’s a bit unclear. My guess is that they are after the semantics of =, !=, >, <, >= and <=, knowing those operators won’t work. If my guess is correct, @MatthewDiana is leading you on the right track.

Comment: A different interpretation would be that they are after `startsWith()`, `equalsIgnoreCase()` and the other instance methods that take a String argument and return a boolean. Can you tell from the context in the book in which they give the exercise?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this task was meant for you to provide your own implementation of string comparison, so for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length(), b.lentgh(); i++) {
  if (a[i] < b[i]) {
    System.out.println("a < b");
    return;
  }
  // ...
```

Strings are objects, not primitives, and cannot be compared with comparison operators. There is a compareTo(String anotherString) method build into String which returns a number depending on which string is lexically greater.

Comment: Leaving aside the guesses about the interpretation of the assignemnt, I think you should at least use `Math.min(a.length(), b.lentgh())` rather than max, or there’s a great risk of a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use relational operators( <, <=, >,>=) on Strings in Java. Java does not rely on operator overloading.

You can use compareTo method for comparing Strings:
The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.